# Wordpress plugin is stripping html tags - how to white list certain tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this plugin
https://themeforest.net/item/upvote-social-bookmarking-wordpress-theme/15542355?ref=ThemeWarriors

The thing is, their plugin doesn't use Wordpress normal posts, it has it's own "post" type which is a "story". When you submit a story then there is no WPEditor , just an empty textarea.

I've added the TinyMce to the textarea to allow users to submit stories that use html formatting but the plugin is stripping the html and converting it to text only.
If I try to submit text using `<strong>test text</strong>` it will show the tag in the story (post).

I've reached out to their support but they state it's beyond their support policy. They asked me to try changing the following but it didn't work:

```
'post_content'    => wp_kses_post( $warrior_description_topic ),
```

to

```
'post_content'    => $warrior_description_topic,
```

The comments section works fine using the TinyMCE Comments WP plugin as the comments is using wordpress system and not the plugin, I just want to be able to use the same editor on the plugins submission page.

The textarea in question is this:

```
<textarea name="description" id="post-desc" rows="8" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Description', 'upvote-plugin'); ?>" required><?php if (isset($_POST['description'])) echo $_POST['description']; ?></textarea>
```

I want to add the TinyMCE editor to the textarea and whitelist certain tags (strong, italic, underline etc)

If you need more info, let me know what to look for like esc_html etc and I'll post the code that's relevant. I can't reveal much of the code as it's a paid plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the TinyMCE editor to that `textarea`, replace the entire tag with:

```
// We use output buffering so that we could modify the TEXTAREA tag, where
// we'll add the "placeholder" and "required" attributes to that tag.
/* Original code:
<textarea name="description" id="post-desc" rows="8" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Description', 'upvote-plugin'); ?>" required><?php if (isset($_POST['description'])) echo $_POST['description']; ?></textarea>
*/
ob_start();
$content = isset( $_POST['description'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['description'] ) : '';
wp_editor( $content, 'post-desc', array(
    'textarea_name' => 'description',
    'textarea_rows' => '8',
    'teeny'         => true, // TRUE to output the minimal editor config, such as the Comment editor.
) );
$editor = ob_get_clean();
$text = esc_html__( 'Description', 'upvote-plugin' );
$editor = str_replace( '<textarea ', '<textarea placeholder="' . $text . '" required ', $editor );
echo $editor;
```

See [wp_editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) for more info on that `function`.

Regarding this one:

> `'post_content'    => $warrior_description_topic`

If that doesn't work, then if possible, please post the code where that variable is defined, where it would look like:

`$warrior_description_topic = // whatever code here.`